# How to get the text from the div menu and make a bold on click from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bind the menu at the run time (i.e .cs file) in the div. When I click on the perticular menu, then those make a bold text from jquery. Please help. example:

```
<div><ul><a>code</a></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *if* that is an accurate portrayal of your mark up, your `<a>` tags should not be directly in the `<ul>` tags, there should be list item tags `<li>` inside the `<ul>`s. Additionally, you will want to add a class/id to the `<ul>` or surrounding `<div>` to aid/specify the jQuery selectors.

That being said here is your markup:

```
<div id="mylist-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a hreh="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a hreh="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a hreh="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the jQuery to go with it:

```
$('#mylist-wrapper a').click(function(){
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('div ul a').live('click', function() {
  $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```